# Mapping between different depencendy managers' (e.g. Maven, Gradle) dependency syntax

Tags: maven, gradle, dependency-management

When I was browsing [MvnRepository](http://mvnrepository.com/), I noticed a pattern. For example if I want to use Spring Framework:

Using Maven I need to add:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.6.SEC03</version>
</dependency>
```

Using Gradle I need to add:

```
'org.springframework:spring:2.5.6.SEC03'
```

So I came to the conclusion that if *groupId = A*, *artifactId = B*, *version = C* in Maven, I have to express it like *'A:B:C'* in Gradle. 
I noticed a similar pattern for Ivy, Grape, Buildr, SBT, Leiningen syntax.

Is it always the rule or only an MvnRepository thing? For example, here is [JLIBSVM](https://github.com/davidsoergel/jlibsvm) which can be found in a custom respository, and on the webpage it is only given how to use it with Maven. Is it compatible with all these other dependency managers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use this syntax in Gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '3.6.7.Final'
}
```

And there are other variations like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile (
        [group: 'foo', name: 'foo', version: '0.1'],
        [group: 'bar', name: 'bar', version: '0.1']
    )
}
```

Also, not all sections are always required. For example if you just have a jar file in a flat directory on your system, you can say:

```
runtime name: 'name'
```

Note the `jar` prefix is omitted.

Gradle and most other dependency managers support declaring dependencies that live in a Maven repository because Maven is ubiquitous. The project you mention is indeed hosted in a Maven repository, just not the Maven Central that you may be used to. When using Gradle for example you have to indicate which Maven repository you want to use in the `repositories` section.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, although there are some more modifiers around